# database(ETL) testing using sql server

Tags: replace, truncate, datalength

for **ETL TESTING:**

when transforming from source table to destination or war house, 
if a column `EMPLOYEENAME` is `null`, replace it with `""` and `truncate` to 50 characters in sql server 2014
  i got a query to replace null with `""`. but i have to truncate the data length if data is `null`.

```
SELECT  
    [EmployeeID], 
    ISNULL( [Employeename],'""') AS [Employeename] 
FROM [dbo].[Employees]
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (MVCE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question and chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question asked..

you need to select records and display " " (Blank) in case of Null and trim it to 50 characters for all records extending above it.

```
   SELECT  
   [EmployeeID], 
       left(ISNULL( [Employeename],'""'),50)   AS [Employeename]
          FROM [dbo].[Employees]
```